# Change page margins for one single page inside the document

Tags: margins, koma-script, landscape

I am writing a document , A4, using KOMA-Scripts (scrbook) and inside my document i have a Flowchart which doesn't pass in portrait. I used

```
 \KOMAoptions{paper=landscape}
 \recalctypearea
 \newgeometry{left=20mm,right=20mm,top=20mm, bottom=20mm}
```

and at the end of the Flowchart, for returning to portrait, i write

```
 \KOMAoptions{paper=portrait}
 \restoregeometry
 \recalctypearea
```

doing this give me what i want, but i get the following Warning:

```
Package typearea Warning: Bad type area settings!
(typearea)               The detected line width is about 48%
(typearea)               larger than the heuristically detected line width.
(typearea)               You should e.g. decrease DIV, increase fontsize
(typearea)               or change papersize.


Package typearea Warning: Typearea changed!
(typearea)                You should do this only at preamble, because only
(typearea)                \begin{document} calculates output dimensions!
(typearea)                Trying to calculate new output dimensions, but
(typearea)                this is only a dirty hack on input line 206.


Overfull \hbox (211.8935pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 314--315
 [] 
[4
Non-PDF special ignored!]

Package typearea Warning: Typearea changed!
(typearea)                You should do this only at preamble, because only
(typearea)                \begin{document} calculates output dimensions!
(typearea)                Trying to calculate new output dimensions, but
(typearea)                this is only a dirty hack on input line 321.
```

How could i solve this warning due to `\recalctypearea`?

**Remark**
I know that `Overfull \hbox is ...` is due to something else

Comment: Is this not possible using the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry)?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `sidewaysfigure` environment from the [rotating](http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating) package?

Comment: @Werner: `geometry` isn't able do use `landscape` with `newgeometry`

Comment: You could also use the [`lscape`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lscape) or [`pdflscape`](http://ctan.org/pdflscape) packages.

Answer (score 8):

You can't disable the warnings. This behaviour is based on the algorithm of `typearea` / `\recalctyparea`. `\recalctypearea` performs its calculations with the last page settings. But by using landscape, the changes to `\textwidth` and `\textheight` are more than 15%. (This is the allowed penalty). `typearea` ignores the modification of the page orientation. Maybe in the next release Markus Kohm will add such a feature.

Comment: Does it mean that way i do it is correct? or is there a better way to switch between portrait to landscape in a KOMA-Script dokument?

Comment: @Eagle: Everything is ok ;-). Markus Kohm offers the same solution on his German website.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel This topic is past for 4.5 years. Unfortunately, I still wasn't able to find a solution to fix this typearea warnings. Could you figure out a fix in the meanwhile?