# Inserting Landscape PDF in printed document

Tags: pdf, landscape, printing

I wonder how to insert a landscape PDF best. Since my document will be printed, I tend to insert it as a portrait rotated left side up. But then it is not well readable on screen. And the Section heading as well as the page number are falsely rotated as well.

So what would be the common way to handle this case? At best with respect to both advantages, the landscape format on screen and printed as rotated portrait with the left side up?

THX!

Comment: An interesting question. I'm not sure whether the PDF standard allows a page to have a different orientation on the screen and on print. However, note that for instance acrobat has "auto rotate pages" checkbox in the printing dialog, which makes the pages appear in the sensible way on the paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a pretty simple solution (even though apparently a "dirty hack") in the `KOMA-script` which I use anyway.

It automatically rotates the `Section title` as well as the `page numbers` which seems to be the most simple way to archieve this.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-4]

    \storeareas\LandscapeArea
    \KOMAoptions{pagesize, paper=landscape, DIV=10} 
        \includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\section{Test}}]{file.pdf}
    \clearpage\LandscapeArea

    \lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Though, this results some warnings here:

> Bad type area settings!(typearea) The detected line width is about 85%(typearea) larger than the heuristically detected line width.

and

> Typearea changed!(typearea) You should do this only at preamble, because only(typearea) \begin{document} calculates output dimensions!(typearea) Trying to calculate new output dimensions, but(typearea) this is only a dirty hack

I just found out, that these are based on the last page settings or rather, that the switch from portrait to landscape causes a change in `textwidth` and `textheight` which is bigger as the allowed penalty 15%.
The full explenation can be found in [Marco Daniels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27562/change-page-margins-for-one-single-page-inside-the-document) post.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution. This works fine for me, with acrobat reader 11

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\includepdf[pages=1,landscape]{file.pdf}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: indeed, but it's not solving the issue with the page number.

Comment: I do not understand, what issue?

Comment: Your solution is partly good! The `section title` and the `page number` are not rotated though.

Comment: you find a solution, very good.

Answer (score 2):

If you use pdfLatex you can use the `pdflscape` package and then use the `landscape` environment.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum} %random text

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{landscape}
\lipsum
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

This only works for the PDF output (the page really apears in landscape mode) as it is impossible to do it with prints. The print will rotate is as a normal a4 paper to print it.

Comment: Unfortunately this solves not the issue with the page numbers