# Change height of header of a single page

Tags: pdftex, koma-script, scrbook

I have a custom page style with a really big header. How do I change the height of the header on one single page or, better, on every page associated with this page style? (Simply, moving the content of the header to the body is not an option for me!)

I know about the option `headheight`. However, it's a global option. Calling

```
\KOMAoption{headheight}{5cm}
\recalctypearea
```

on a new page won't change the header. Instead, I get the error `\headheight to low.` What makes it even more curious is that if I change the value of `headheight` to something really big, like 15cm, the header will all of a sudden become this big.

Comment: Please post a MWE. Do you also use `geometry` (probably not if you use KOMA calculations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the following way. Please note the hints provided by the documentation and you have to accept the warnings [Change page margins for one single page inside the document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27562/change-page-margins-for-one-single-page-inside-the-document)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant[1-2]
\clearpage
\storeareas\SmallHeadHeight
\KOMAoption{headheight}{5cm}
\recalctypearea
\kant[3-4]
\clearpage\SmallHeadHeight
\kant[5-6]
\end{document}
```